# Is there a way to seperate the residual terms in lmer function in r?

Tags: r, spss, mixed-models

I am trying to run a linear mixed effects model on the data:

```
maleID  femaleID  dyadID  session  wai  male  female 
55      100       55_100  1        4.75 1     0
55      100       55_100  2        5    1     0
55      100       55_100  1        3.25 0     1
55      100       55_100  2        4.25 0     1
55      101       55_101  1        4    1     0
55      101       55_101  2        6    1     0
55      101       55_101  1        5    0     1           
55      101       55_101  2        4    0     1
59      101       59_101  1        5.25 1     0
59      101       59_101  2        3.5  1     0
59      101       59_101  1        4.5  0     1
59      101       59_101  2        6.5  0     1
59      102       59_102  1        5    1     0
59      102       59_102  2        6    1     0
59      102       59_102  1        5.75 0     1
59      102       59_102  2        5.25 0     1
```

and so on...
wai is the dependent variable, male and female is dummy codes variables, and MaleID, femaleID and dyadID are unique identifiers.

I used the following code in R for a mixed linear model:

```
lmer(wai ~ 0 + male + female + session + 
       (0 + male + female|maleID) + 
       (0 + male + female|femaleID),
     data=data, na.action=na.exclude, REML=TRUE)
```

The 'male' and 'female' variables are dummy coded, signaling the model to create two separate random effects, one for male ratings and one for female ratings.
but, I get only one single residual component. My question is there is a way to do the same for the error/residual terms of the model? that is, to create seperate residual variance, one for the male ratings and one for female ratings?

the last 'REPEATED' statement in the following SPSS syntax does so:

```
MIXED wai WITH male female BY maleID femaleID dyadID
    /FIXED = male female session | NOINT
    /METHOD=REML
    /PRINT=SOLUTION TESTCOV
    /RANDOM=male female | SUBJECT (dyadID) COVTYPE (csh)
    /RANDOM=male female | SUBJECT (maleID) COVTYPE (csh)
    /RANDOM=male female | SUBJECT (femaleID) COVTYPE (csh)
    /REPEATED=male female | SUBJECT (dyadID*maleID*femaleID*session) COVTYPE (vc)
```

note that the by using the “NOINT” command and the dummy codes of man and female preceding it, Im suppressing the general intercept so that I can obtain separate variances for the male and female subgroups.
my question is there is a way to do so in R?

Comment: https://rpubs.com/bbolker/factorvar